# connected my QY7 headsets to elementary OS freya

Tags: bluetooth

You can see in the picture that my QY7 headsets were recognized
 as a keyboard and the sound menu doesn't show any other sound output[image]

Comment: sorry, I am unable to get your question."any other " means?Will you please more specific ?

Comment: In Windows i've the same problem but i resolved intalling the driver for my bluetooth but in elementary only take the headset as a keyboard, and in the configutation don't show any device for sound output